# Have a random number equal something with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, random, numbers

I have a function that when you click an image, it generates a random number. If that random number = 5, then the number is erased and it says Winner, otherwise it says you're a loser. Here is my Javascript code:

```
function randomNumber()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("Button")
    x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
}
if (x.innerHTML == 5);
{
    x.innerHTML("WINNER!!!");
}
else
{ 
    x.innerHTML("LOOSER!!!");
}
```

And here is my HTML

```
<p id="Button">
    <img src="poke.png" onclick="randomNumber()">
</p>
```

So, what I want it to do, is that when the image is clicked, instead of a random number, it tells you if you're a winner, or a looser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign your random number to a variable and then check if it is equal to 5. You should then compare that variable if it equals to 5 and modify your innerHTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myTimer;

function myTimerF()
{
var x=document.getElementById("Button");
x.innerHTML="<img src='poke.png' >";
clearInterval(myTimer);
}

function randomNumber()
{
var res = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);

var x=document.getElementById("Button")
if(res == 5)
    x.innerHTML = "Winner!";
else
    x.innerHTML = "Looser!";

    myTimer=setInterval(function(){myTimerF()},1000);
}
</head>
<body>
    <p id="Button" onclick="randomNumber()">
    <img src="poke.png" >
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the timer code too.

Comment: Question, is there anyway to make the button press able again after it's been pressed? because you have to reload the page to press it again, and the odds are so low that you'd literally have to spam click it for a long time to win.

Comment: You can use a timer to revert back to your image after say 1 second.

Comment: Sorry for being a newb, but how would I do that?

Comment: I have added the modified code to the original answer. Pls check that

Answer (score 1):

Here, check this.

```
<body>
<button id="Button" onClick="randomNumber();">press me</button>
</body>


<script>
function randomNumber()
{
    var btn=document.getElementById("Button");
    var x=Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
    if (x == 5) {
        btn.innerHTML = "WINNER!!!";
    } else { 
        btn.innerHTML = "LOOSER!!!";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: And you don't even need to add 1 there, as it doesn't affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the button to tell the user if they won or not, you can simple do this.

```
function check_winner() {
    var x = document.getElementById('button');
    if(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) == 5)
        x.innerHTML = 'WINNER!!!';
    else
        x.innerHTML = 'LOSER!!!';
}
```

Comment: Um why is the html not getting displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jokey's answer (code almost copypasted) as to how it works:

- You don't need to put the random value in the `innerHTML`, you can put it in a variable or just in the  condition.
- `innerHTML` is a property, not a function.
- You don't need to add 1, as it won't affect the result.

```javascript
function randomNumber()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("Button");
    if (Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) == 5) {
        btn.innerHTML = "WINNER!!!";
    } else { 
        btn.innerHTML = "LOOSER!!!";
    }
}
```